# Exception in libgdx TextureRegion class

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I was following a tutorial to create a pokemon like game with libgdx library in java.
I am stuck on making the walking animation part because of the libgdx update on Animation , so the animation should be set to TextureRegion each time displayed(if I am not mistaken ).

```
public TextureRegion getSprite() {
        if (state == ACTOR_STATE.WALKING) {
            Animation<TextureRegion> walkingAnimation = animations.getWalking(facing);
            return walkingAnimation.getKeyFrame(walkTimer);
        } else if (state == ACTOR_STATE.STANDING) {
            return animations.getStanding(facing);
        }
        return animations.getStanding(DIRECTION.SOUTH);
    }
```

This is the method getSprite and the game is crashing after trying to move ( it makes a small move but before ending it crashes ) with this exception on the  return walkingAnimation.getKeyFrame(walkTimer); line:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation$PlayMode cannot be cast to class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion (com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation$PlayMode and com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

The variable animations is set like :
 `private AnimationSet<TextureRegion> animations;`
and the AnimationSet class:

```
package util;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import model.DIRECTION;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;



    public class AnimationSet<TextureRegion> {

        private Map<DIRECTION, Animation<TextureRegion>> walking;
        private Map<DIRECTION, TextureRegion> standing;

        public AnimationSet(Animation<TextureRegion> walkNorth,
                            Animation<TextureRegion> walkSouth,
                            Animation<TextureRegion> walkEast,
                            Animation<TextureRegion> walkWest,
                            TextureRegion standNorth,
                            TextureRegion standSouth,
                            TextureRegion standEast,
                            TextureRegion standWest ) {
            walking = new HashMap<DIRECTION, Animation<TextureRegion>>();
            walking.put(DIRECTION.NORTH, walkNorth);
            walking.put(DIRECTION.SOUTH, walkSouth);
            walking.put(DIRECTION.EAST, walkEast);
            walking.put(DIRECTION.WEST, walkWest);
            standing = new Hashtable<DIRECTION, TextureRegion>();
            standing.put(DIRECTION.NORTH, standNorth);
            standing.put(DIRECTION.SOUTH, standSouth);
            standing.put(DIRECTION.EAST, standEast);
            standing.put(DIRECTION.WEST, standWest);
        }

        public Animation<TextureRegion> getWalking(DIRECTION dir){
            return walking.get(dir);
        }

        public TextureRegion getStanding(DIRECTION dir){
            return standing.get(dir);
        }
    }
```

Finally it's called here:

```
 public GameScreen(MyGdxGame app) {
        super(app);
        south = new Texture("assets/stand.png");
        room1 = new Texture("assets/tile2.png");
        room2 = new Texture("assets/tile2.png");
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        TextureAtlas atlas = app.getAssetManager().get("assets/packed/textures.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        AnimationSet animations = new AnimationSet(
                new Animation(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegion("dawn_walk_north"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                new Animation(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegion("dawn_walk_south"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                new Animation(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegion("dawn_walk_east"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                new Animation(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegion("dawn_walk_west"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_north"),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_south"),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_east"),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_west")
        );

        map = new TileMap(10,10);
        actor = new Actor(map,0,0,animations);
        controller = new PlayerController(actor);
        camera = new Camera();
    }
```

I've tried to see the getWalking(facing) and walkTimer values on debugger but nothing seems to be null or wrong with this part.
Also in the version I uploaded i casted Animation before returning to make sure the returned object is Animation and not Object.
Same exception happens without casting. Could the error  be somewhere on the GameScreen class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer , in the new GameScreen the animations should be set with `new Animation<TextureRegion>`, and `atlas.findRegion` should be replaced with `atlas.findRegions`. That solved the problem and the movement is working correctly.
Finally the correct code for GameScreen class is:

```js
AnimationSet<TextureRegion> animations = new AnimationSet<TextureRegion>(
                new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegions("dawn_walk_north"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegions("dawn_walk_south"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegions("dawn_walk_east"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.3f/2f,atlas.findRegions("dawn_walk_west"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_north"),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_south"),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_east"),
                atlas.findRegion("dawn_stand_west")
        );
```